# Tortoise SVN запуск из командной строки под системной учеткой

Tags: 1с, svn, tortoise-svn

*Отступление:
Пытаюсь работать с svn.exe из 1С, использую 
`ЗапуститьПриложение()`, для меня важно, что бы процедура выполнялась на сервере (&НаСервере)* 

Но на самом деле не суть кто запускает svn.exe, 1С или любое другое приложение, проблема в том, что СП (сервер приложений) 1С (т.е. служба) запускается под системной учеткой. Если запускать службу под тек. учеткой, все работает. 
Перепробовал кучу параметров, указывал явно на расположения конфига, но все равно не пашет, возвращает код ответа 1.

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" update D:\SVN\Progect\Templates --username admin --no-auth-cache --non-interactive --config-dir "D:\SubversionConfig" --trust-server-cert
```

Понять что именно не так не могу, т.к. фиг знает как добиться от svn что ему не нравится.

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" update D:\SVN\Progect\Templates --username admin --no-auth-cache --non-interactive --config-dir "D:\SubversionConfig" --trust-server-cert > "D:1.txt"
```

файл не создается, да, может тут особенность работы `ЗапуститьПриложение()`, но что есть то есть. Подскажите как можно решить проблему.

Comment: Сам же и отвечаешь на свой вопрос: Создай новую учетную запись с правами Администратора на сервере; Запускай службу под этой учеткой;

Comment: Не могу я гарантировать, что служба будет запущена не под системной учеткой. Вопрос в другом, почему это SVN не хочет работать под системной учеткой, я же передаю ему логин и пароль